# Model is not populated during form post ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am learning ASP.NET MVC. I am trying to catch model data on form post, but model is showing as null.

Here is my Model

```
public class SampleModel
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CRUDOperation { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<SampleModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitUpdateGridRow", "GridView", FormMethod.Post, new {value =      "form" }))
{ 
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("CRUD Actions")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (SampleModel Row in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            @if (Row.CRUDOperation == "Select")
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Update", "UpdateGridRow", "GridView", Row, new {  @title = "U: Update Operation of CRUD" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditGridRow", "GridView", new { id =  Row.BGID }, new { @title = "U: Update Operation of CRUD" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteGridRow", "GridView", new { id =  Row.BGID }, new { @title = "D: Delete Operation of CRUD" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsGridRow", "GridView", new { id  = Row.BGID }, new { @title = "Form level view for details" })
                </td>
                <td>                       
                    @Row.ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Row.Name
                </td>
            }
            else if (Row.CRUDOperation == "Edit")
            {                                        
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(ID => Row.ID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(CRUDOperation => Row.CRUDOperation)
                    @Row.BGID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(Name => Row.Name)
                </td>
                <td>                        
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" id="UpdateSubmit" />                        
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditGridRow", "GridView", new { id =  Row.ID }, new { @title = "U: Update Operation of CRUD" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Reset", "ResetGridRow", "GridView", new { id = Row.ID }, new { @title = "R: Reset Operation of CRUD" })                        
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
        @*<tr>
            @if (Row.CRUDOperation == "Edit")
            {
                EditRow(Row);
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayRow(Row);
            }
        </tr>*@
        //Row.CRUDOperation.Equals("Edit") ? EditRow(Row) : DisplayRow(Row);
    }
 </table>    
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public class GridViewController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult SubmitUpdateGridRow(FormCollection FC, SampleModel VM)
    {
        string str = (string)FC.GetValue("Row.Name").AttemptedValue;
         ......             
    }
}
```

I was able to get the values from form collection, but my model is coming as null.

Thanks in advance.

PS: i would like to find the solution only with server side scripting, dont want to use javascript, JQuery

Comment: how u r submitting ur from with input type submit or input type button??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you are posting a collection of `SampleModel` however your controller only takes in a single `SampleModel` parameter.

First you need to change your controller to take in `IEnumerable<SampleModel>`.

Then in your view, you need to pass the index to the html helpers to generate the correct html for list model binding to work out of the box.

For example:

```
@model IList<SampleModel>

@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
}
```

Check this useful [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) for more on model binding lists

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked.
but i dont need to change the controller, to take    IEnumerable<SampleModel>
bcoz i am sending only one SampleModel Object to controller on "Insert" Submit button click.

Answer (score -1):

Put Antiforgery attribute on top of the controller action as your HTML form has Antiforgery tag.